# How can I get my counter to stop at a defined point?

Tags: jquery

I have built a counter that goes up by a number but I want it to stop when it gets to a defined point (end_value) and I'm not really sure where to even start with this.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var increment = 1;
var start_value = 1;
var count = 0;
var end_value = 10;

window.onload = function(){

    var interval_time = 1 * 1500;

    count = parseInt (start_value);
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

    setInterval("count += increment; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", interval_time);
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `setInterval` returns an id value that can be use to `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `id` returned by `setInterval` and add logic to your callback to `clearInterval` when `count === end_value`:

```js
var increment = 1;
var start_value = 1;
var count = 0;
var end_value = 10;

window.onload = function() {

  var interval_time = 1 * 1500;

  count = parseInt(start_value);
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

  var id = setInterval(function() {
    count += increment;
    if (count === end_value) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

  }, interval_time);
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your interval to a variable.

`var my_interval = setInterval(function(){}, interval_time);`

Run a loop or use callback to clear the interval

`clearInterval(my_interval)`